# send a datastructure to ajax

Tags: javascript

this is how i now receive the php response

```
var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

the php script echos the response.

how can i send a datastructure from php to javascript ? echoing the response it very difficult and not so powerfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode` on the PHP end
&
`JSON.parse` on the javascript side

Answer (score 1):

Json is the easiest way.  http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

JSon is your friend http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

The php functions encoding/decoding data structures with JSON are... well, json_encode and json_decode :)

Answer (score 1):

In server side php just do `json_encode(/*your response from the database*/)` and by using ajax u will get the response like

```
var json_result =  JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```